# TailwindCSS 3 - Build CSS only specified classes in contents

Tags: tailwind-css

My project use tailwind with class prefix which is `sd-`..

I run `npx tailwindcss -o ./dist/css/vue3-datatable.css` to build the output css file..

It will generate a single css file... In the single css file, there will have TWO parts, which are:

.

PART #1

```
/*
! tailwindcss v3.1.6 | MIT License | https://tailwindcss.com
*/

/*
1. Prevent padding and border from affecting element width. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/4)
2. Allow adding a border to an element by just adding a border-width. (https://github.com/tailwindcss/tailwindcss/pull/116)
*/

*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  /* 2 */
  border-style: solid;
  /* 2 */
  border-color: #e5e7eb;
  /* 2 */
}

::before,
::after {
  --tw-content: '';
}

/*
1. Use a consistent sensible line-height in all browsers.
2. Prevent adjustments of font size after orientation changes in iOS.
3. Use a more readable tab size.
4. Use the user's configured `sans` font-family by default.
*/

html {
  line-height: 1.5;
  /* 1 */
  -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;
  /* 2 */
  /* 3 */
  tab-size: 4;
  /* 3 */
  font-family: ui-sans-serif, system-ui, -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, "Noto Sans", sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
  /* 4 */
}

/*
1. Remove the margin in all browsers.
2. Inherit line-height from `html` so users can set them as a class directly on the `html` element.
*/

body {
  margin: 0;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
1. Add the correct height in Firefox.
2. Correct the inheritance of border color in Firefox. (https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=190655)
3. Ensure horizontal rules are visible by default.
*/

hr {
  height: 0;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-top-width: 1px;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Add the correct text decoration in Chrome, Edge, and Safari.
*/

abbr:where([title]) {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline dotted;
          text-decoration: underline dotted;
}

/*
Remove the default font size and weight for headings.
*/

h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-size: inherit;
  font-weight: inherit;
}

/*
Reset links to optimize for opt-in styling instead of opt-out.
*/

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: inherit;
}

/*
Add the correct font weight in Edge and Safari.
*/

b,
strong {
  font-weight: bolder;
}

/*
1. Use the user's configured `mono` font family by default.
2. Correct the odd `em` font sizing in all browsers.
*/

code,
kbd,
samp,
pre {
  font-family: ui-monospace, SFMono-Regular, Menlo, Monaco, Consolas, "Liberation Mono", "Courier New", monospace;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 1em;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct font size in all browsers.
*/

small {
  font-size: 80%;
}

/*
Prevent `sub` and `sup` elements from affecting the line height in all browsers.
*/

sub,
sup {
  font-size: 75%;
  line-height: 0;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

sub {
  bottom: -0.25em;
}

sup {
  top: -0.5em;
}

/*
1. Remove text indentation from table contents in Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=999088, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=201297)
2. Correct table border color inheritance in all Chrome and Safari. (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=935729, https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195016)
3. Remove gaps between table borders by default.
*/

table {
  text-indent: 0;
  /* 1 */
  border-color: inherit;
  /* 2 */
  border-collapse: collapse;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
1. Change the font styles in all browsers.
2. Remove the margin in Firefox and Safari.
3. Remove default padding in all browsers.
*/

button,
input,
optgroup,
select,
textarea {
  font-family: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  font-size: 100%;
  /* 1 */
  font-weight: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  line-height: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  color: inherit;
  /* 1 */
  margin: 0;
  /* 2 */
  padding: 0;
  /* 3 */
}

/*
Remove the inheritance of text transform in Edge and Firefox.
*/

button,
select {
  text-transform: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Remove default button styles.
*/

button,
[type='button'],
[type='reset'],
[type='submit'] {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* 2 */
  background-image: none;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Use the modern Firefox focus style for all focusable elements.
*/

:-moz-focusring {
  outline: auto;
}

/*
Remove the additional `:invalid` styles in Firefox. (https://github.com/mozilla/gecko-dev/blob/2f9eacd9d3d995c937b4251a5557d95d494c9be1/layout/style/res/forms.css#L728-L737)
*/

:-moz-ui-invalid {
  box-shadow: none;
}

/*
Add the correct vertical alignment in Chrome and Firefox.
*/

progress {
  vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*
Correct the cursor style of increment and decrement buttons in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
::-webkit-outer-spin-button {
  height: auto;
}

/*
1. Correct the odd appearance in Chrome and Safari.
2. Correct the outline style in Safari.
*/

[type='search'] {
  -webkit-appearance: textfield;
  /* 1 */
  outline-offset: -2px;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Remove the inner padding in Chrome and Safari on macOS.
*/

::-webkit-search-decoration {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

/*
1. Correct the inability to style clickable types in iOS and Safari.
2. Change font properties to `inherit` in Safari.
*/

::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  -webkit-appearance: button;
  /* 1 */
  font: inherit;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Add the correct display in Chrome and Safari.
*/

summary {
  display: list-item;
}

/*
Removes the default spacing and border for appropriate elements.
*/

blockquote,
dl,
dd,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
hr,
figure,
p,
pre {
  margin: 0;
}

fieldset {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

legend {
  padding: 0;
}

ol,
ul,
menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

/*
Prevent resizing textareas horizontally by default.
*/

textarea {
  resize: vertical;
}

/*
1. Reset the default placeholder opacity in Firefox. (https://github.com/tailwindlabs/tailwindcss/issues/3300)
2. Set the default placeholder color to the user's configured gray 400 color.
*/

input:-ms-input-placeholder, textarea:-ms-input-placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}

input::placeholder,
textarea::placeholder {
  opacity: 1;
  /* 1 */
  color: #9ca3af;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Set the default cursor for buttons.
*/

button,
[role="button"] {
  cursor: pointer;
}

/*
Make sure disabled buttons don't get the pointer cursor.
*/

:disabled {
  cursor: default;
}

/*
1. Make replaced elements `display: block` by default. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
2. Add `vertical-align: middle` to align replaced elements more sensibly by default. (https://github.com/jensimmons/cssremedy/issues/14#issuecomment-634934210)
   This can trigger a poorly considered lint error in some tools but is included by design.
*/

img,
svg,
video,
canvas,
audio,
iframe,
embed,
object {
  display: block;
  /* 1 */
  vertical-align: middle;
  /* 2 */
}

/*
Constrain images and videos to the parent width and preserve their intrinsic aspect ratio. (https://github.com/mozdevs/cssremedy/issues/14)
*/

img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

*, ::before, ::after {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}

::backdrop {
  --tw-border-spacing-x: 0;
  --tw-border-spacing-y: 0;
  --tw-translate-x: 0;
  --tw-translate-y: 0;
  --tw-rotate: 0;
  --tw-skew-x: 0;
  --tw-skew-y: 0;
  --tw-scale-x: 1;
  --tw-scale-y: 1;
  --tw-pan-x:  ;
  --tw-pan-y:  ;
  --tw-pinch-zoom:  ;
  --tw-scroll-snap-strictness: proximity;
  --tw-ordinal:  ;
  --tw-slashed-zero:  ;
  --tw-numeric-figure:  ;
  --tw-numeric-spacing:  ;
  --tw-numeric-fraction:  ;
  --tw-ring-inset:  ;
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 0px;
  --tw-ring-offset-color: #fff;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(59 130 246 / 0.5);
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-ring-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-blur:  ;
  --tw-brightness:  ;
  --tw-contrast:  ;
  --tw-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-invert:  ;
  --tw-saturate:  ;
  --tw-sepia:  ;
  --tw-drop-shadow:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-blur:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-brightness:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-contrast:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-grayscale:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-hue-rotate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-invert:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-opacity:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-saturate:  ;
  --tw-backdrop-sepia:  ;
}
```

.

PART #2

```
.sd-sr-only {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: -1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  white-space: nowrap;
  border-width: 0;
}

.sd-fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

.sd-absolute {
  position: absolute;
}

.sd-relative {
  position: relative;
}

.sd-inset-0 {
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
}

.sd-top-0 {
  top: 0px;
}

.sd-right-0 {
  right: 0px;
}

.sd-z-10 {
  z-index: 10;
}

.sd-z-0 {
  z-index: 0;
}

.sd-z-50 {
  z-index: 50;
}

.sd-col-span-4 {
  grid-column: span 4 / span 4;
}

.-sd-my-2 {
  margin-top: -0.5rem;
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
}

.-sd-mx-4 {
  margin-left: -1rem;
  margin-right: -1rem;
}

.sd-mt-10 {
  margin-top: 2.5rem;
}

.sd-mt-3 {
  margin-top: 0.75rem;
}

.sd-mr-4 {
  margin-right: 1rem;
}

.sd-mr-2 {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.sd-mb-4 {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.sd-mb-2 {
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.sd-ml-2 {
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
}

.sd-mt-1 {
  margin-top: 0.25rem;
}

.sd-mt-4 {
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.sd-mr-1 {
  margin-right: 0.25rem;
}

.sd-block {
  display: block;
}

.sd-inline-block {
  display: inline-block;
}

.sd-flex {
  display: flex;
}

.sd-inline-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}

.sd-grid {
  display: grid;
}

.sd-h-16 {
  height: 4rem;
}

.sd-h-5 {
  height: 1.25rem;
}

.sd-h-full {
  height: 100%;
}

.sd-w-5 {
  width: 1.25rem;
}

.sd-w-full {
  width: 100%;
}

.sd-min-w-full {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.sd-max-w-2xl {
  max-width: 42rem;
}

.sd-max-w-lg {
  max-width: 32rem;
}

.sd-translate-y-4 {
  --tw-translate-y: 1rem;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
}

.sd-translate-y-0 {
  --tw-translate-y: 0px;
  transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
}

.sd-cursor-default {
  cursor: default;
}

.sd-cursor-pointer {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sd-select-none {
  -webkit-user-select: none;
      -ms-user-select: none;
          user-select: none;
}

.sd-list-none {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.sd-appearance-none {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
}

.sd-grid-cols-2 {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(0, 1fr));
}

.sd-flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}

.sd-items-center {
  align-items: center;
}

.sd-justify-center {
  justify-content: center;
}

.sd-gap-4 {
  gap: 1rem;
}

.-sd-space-x-px > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
  --tw-space-x-reverse: 0;
  margin-right: calc(-1px * var(--tw-space-x-reverse));
  margin-left: calc(-1px * calc(1 - var(--tw-space-x-reverse)));
}

.sd-divide-y > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
  --tw-divide-y-reverse: 0;
  border-top-width: calc(1px * calc(1 - var(--tw-divide-y-reverse)));
  border-bottom-width: calc(1px * var(--tw-divide-y-reverse));
}

.sd-divide-gray-300 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
  --tw-divide-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(209 213 219 / var(--tw-divide-opacity));
}

.sd-divide-gray-200 > :not([hidden]) ~ :not([hidden]) {
  --tw-divide-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(229 231 235 / var(--tw-divide-opacity));
}

.sd-overflow-hidden {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sd-overflow-x-auto {
  overflow-x: auto;
}

.sd-overflow-y-auto {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.sd-whitespace-nowrap {
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.sd-rounded-md {
  border-radius: 0.375rem;
}

.sd-rounded {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}

.sd-rounded-l-md {
  border-top-left-radius: 0.375rem;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0.375rem;
}

.sd-rounded-r-md {
  border-top-right-radius: 0.375rem;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0.375rem;
}

.sd-border {
  border-width: 1px;
}

.sd-border-0 {
  border-width: 0px;
}

.sd-border-b {
  border-bottom-width: 1px;
}

.sd-border-gray-300 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(209 213 219 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}

.sd-border-indigo-500 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(99 102 241 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}

.sd-border-gray-200 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(229 231 235 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}

.sd-border-transparent {
  border-color: transparent;
}

.sd-bg-gray-50 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(249 250 251 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.sd-bg-white {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.sd-bg-indigo-50 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(238 242 255 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.sd-bg-gray-700 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(55 65 81 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.sd-bg-gray-200 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(229 231 235 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.sd-bg-gray-100 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(243 244 246 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.sd-bg-red-600 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(220 38 38 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.sd-bg-indigo-600 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(79 70 229 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.sd-bg-opacity-75 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 0.75;
}

.sd-bg-opacity-60 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 0.6;
}

.sd-bg-none {
  background-image: none;
}

.sd-p-6 {
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.sd-py-2 {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.sd-px-3 {
  padding-left: 0.75rem;
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}

.sd-py-4 {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.sd-px-2 {
  padding-left: 0.5rem;
  padding-right: 0.5rem;
}

.sd-py-3 {
  padding-top: 0.75rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.75rem;
}

.sd-px-6 {
  padding-left: 1.5rem;
  padding-right: 1.5rem;
}

.sd-py-1 {
  padding-top: 0.25rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.25rem;
}

.sd-px-1\.5 {
  padding-left: 0.375rem;
  padding-right: 0.375rem;
}

.sd-px-1 {
  padding-left: 0.25rem;
  padding-right: 0.25rem;
}

.sd-px-4 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}

.sd-pl-4 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.sd-pr-3 {
  padding-right: 0.75rem;
}

.sd-text-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.sd-text-right {
  text-align: right;
}

.sd-align-middle {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.sd-text-sm {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  line-height: 1.25rem;
}

.sd-font-medium {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.sd-font-semibold {
  font-weight: 600;
}

.sd-text-gray-300 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(209 213 219 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.sd-text-gray-600 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(75 85 99 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.sd-text-gray-500 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(107 114 128 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.sd-text-gray-400 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(156 163 175 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.sd-text-gray-900 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(17 24 39 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.sd-text-indigo-600 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(79 70 229 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.sd-text-gray-700 {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(55 65 81 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.sd-text-white {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.sd-opacity-0 {
  opacity: 0;
}

.sd-opacity-100 {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sd-opacity-25 {
  opacity: 0.25;
}

.sd-shadow {
  --tw-shadow: 0 1px 3px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1), 0 1px 2px -1px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.1);
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 1px 3px 0 var(--tw-shadow-color), 0 1px 2px -1px var(--tw-shadow-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
}

.sd-shadow-sm {
  --tw-shadow: 0 1px 2px 0 rgb(0 0 0 / 0.05);
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 1px 2px 0 var(--tw-shadow-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
}

.sd-ring-1 {
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);
  --tw-ring-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 calc(1px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow), var(--tw-ring-shadow), var(--tw-shadow, 0 0 #0000);
}

.sd-ring-black {
  --tw-ring-opacity: 1;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(0 0 0 / var(--tw-ring-opacity));
}

.sd-ring-opacity-5 {
  --tw-ring-opacity: 0.05;
}

.sd-duration-300 {
  transition-duration: 300ms;
}

.sd-duration-200 {
  transition-duration: 200ms;
}

.sd-ease-out {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

.sd-ease-in {
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.4, 0, 1, 1);
}

.hover\:sd-bg-gray-50:hover {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(249 250 251 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.hover\:sd-bg-red-700:hover {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(185 28 28 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.hover\:sd-bg-indigo-700:hover {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(67 56 202 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}

.focus\:sd-border-0:focus {
  border-width: 0px;
}

.focus\:sd-border-indigo-300:focus {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(165 180 252 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}

.focus\:sd-border-indigo-500:focus {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(99 102 241 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}

.focus\:sd-shadow-none:focus {
  --tw-shadow: 0 0 #0000;
  --tw-shadow-colored: 0 0 #0000;
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-ring-shadow, 0 0 #0000), var(--tw-shadow);
}

.focus\:sd-outline-none:focus {
  outline: 2px solid transparent;
  outline-offset: 2px;
}

.focus\:sd-ring-0:focus {
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);
  --tw-ring-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 calc(0px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow), var(--tw-ring-shadow), var(--tw-shadow, 0 0 #0000);
}

.focus\:sd-ring:focus {
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);
  --tw-ring-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 calc(3px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow), var(--tw-ring-shadow), var(--tw-shadow, 0 0 #0000);
}

.focus\:sd-ring-2:focus {
  --tw-ring-offset-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 var(--tw-ring-offset-width) var(--tw-ring-offset-color);
  --tw-ring-shadow: var(--tw-ring-inset) 0 0 0 calc(2px + var(--tw-ring-offset-width)) var(--tw-ring-color);
  box-shadow: var(--tw-ring-offset-shadow), var(--tw-ring-shadow), var(--tw-shadow, 0 0 #0000);
}

.focus\:sd-ring-indigo-200:focus {
  --tw-ring-opacity: 1;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(199 210 254 / var(--tw-ring-opacity));
}

.focus\:sd-ring-indigo-500:focus {
  --tw-ring-opacity: 1;
  --tw-ring-color: rgb(99 102 241 / var(--tw-ring-opacity));
}

.focus\:sd-ring-opacity-50:focus {
  --tw-ring-opacity: 0.5;
}

.focus\:sd-ring-offset-2:focus {
  --tw-ring-offset-width: 2px;
}

@media (min-width: 640px) {
  .sm\:-sd-mx-6 {
    margin-left: -1.5rem;
    margin-right: -1.5rem;
  }

  .sm\:sd-grid {
    display: grid;
  }

  .sm\:sd-w-auto {
    width: auto;
  }

  .sm\:sd-translate-y-0 {
    --tw-translate-y: 0px;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
  }

  .sm\:sd-scale-95 {
    --tw-scale-x: .95;
    --tw-scale-y: .95;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
  }

  .sm\:sd-scale-100 {
    --tw-scale-x: 1;
    --tw-scale-y: 1;
    transform: translate(var(--tw-translate-x), var(--tw-translate-y)) rotate(var(--tw-rotate)) skewX(var(--tw-skew-x)) skewY(var(--tw-skew-y)) scaleX(var(--tw-scale-x)) scaleY(var(--tw-scale-y));
  }

  .sm\:sd-grid-cols-5 {
    grid-template-columns: repeat(5, minmax(0, 1fr));
  }

  .sm\:sd-gap-2 {
    gap: 0.5rem;
  }

  .sm\:sd-rounded-lg {
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .sm\:sd-rounded-t-lg {
    border-top-left-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-top-right-radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .sm\:sd-rounded-b-lg {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 0.5rem;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .sm\:sd-pl-6 {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
  }

  .sm\:sd-text-sm {
    font-size: 0.875rem;
    line-height: 1.25rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .md\:sd-rounded-lg {
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
  }

  .md\:sd-px-6 {
    padding-left: 1.5rem;
    padding-right: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  .lg\:-sd-mx-8 {
    margin-left: -2rem;
    margin-right: -2rem;
  }

  .lg\:sd-px-8 {
    padding-left: 2rem;
    padding-right: 2rem;
  }
}
```

.

so, what I expected here is to only generate single css file with `PART #2` only...

I don't want `PART #1` in my css file...

how can I do that?

how can I generate single css file without `PART #1`?

Answer (score 1):

Just don't include `@tailwind base` in your CSS file - see [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight)

> Built on top of modern-normalize, Preflight is a set of base styles for Tailwind projects that are designed to smooth over cross-browser inconsistencies and make it easier for you to work within the constraints of your design system. Tailwind automatically injects these styles when you include @tailwind base in your CSS:

Answer (score 1):

It could be better to [disabling the preflight](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#disabling-preflight) from the config.

```json
corePlugins: {
  preflight: false,
},
```

If you don't import base, ok you remove the preflight but without tailwind variables.

And you will can't use things as "scale"… for instance.